# iOS waiting screen

Tags: ios

When my app is launched I'd like to display a kind of "waiting view" so I can make the first http calls before accessing to the app.
I saw a nice one, all grey and a little transparent with only an activity indicator inside.
I do not really know how to build this kind of view in a good manner, is it a simple UIView ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MBProgressHUD might be what you're looking for:
https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD

[image]

Comment: thanks, I've already used this one in the past and I remember it's a great one. Is this configurable to the height and width can be ajusted to fit screen size minus "a couple of pixel" ?

Answer (score 12):

Fist short answer is: yes, the simplest way is to use a UIActivityIndicatorView.

**If you don't like all this "big" static libraries just use this:**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

.....

- (UIActivityIndicatorView *)showActivityIndicatorOnView:(UIView*)aView
{
    CGSize viewSize = aView.bounds.size;

    // create new dialog box view and components
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
    initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    // other size? change it
    activityIndicatorView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 65);
    activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    activityIndicatorView.alpha = 0.7f;
    activityIndicatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    activityIndicatorView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;

    // display it in the center of your view
    activityIndicatorView.center = CGPointMake(viewSize.width / 2.0, viewSize.height / 2.0);

    [aView addSubview:activityIndicatorView];

    [activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

    return activityIndicatorView;
}
```

This needs access to a QuartzCore class so add it in to you frameworks. After you task is done send it a stopAnimating and it will disappear. If you don't need it anymore remove it from your view to save memory (btw. this is ARC code).

I call it like this

```
self.activityIndicatorView = [self showActivityIndicatorOnView:self.parentViewController.view];
```

In this case I have UINavigationViewController as a main view controller in my app. This is importent because the activity indicator should show up in the middle of the screen and not e.g. in the middle of a table view.

The simplest implementation is this:

```
- (UIActivityIndicatorView *)showSimpleActivityIndicatorOnView:(UIView*)aView
{
    CGSize viewSize = aView.bounds.size;

    // create new dialog box view and components
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    activityIndicatorView.center = CGPointMake(viewSize.width / 2.0, viewSize.height / 2.0);

    [aView addSubview:activityIndicatorView];

    [activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

    return activityIndicatorView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many many way to do this, but yes, it can be a simple `UIView`.

Maybe you should give a look at [three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) library which offers built-in loaders `TTActivityLabel` like these:

[image: TTActivityLabel]

Comment: g, is there a way better than another ?

Comment: I prefer using a framework like three20 which offers this and much more, but it is complex at first use. It really depends on your needs. Just adding a `UIView`, with transparency `.alpha = .5f` including why not a  `UILabel` and a `UISpinner` and you're done

Comment: g, In fact I'd like to create a grey / transparent View that will take 'almost' the full screen and which will give the impression to float other a black background for instance.

Comment: You can also just use a semitransparent UIImageView with anything *"photoshop-ed"* in it for a particular rendering... It is really not that hard to do, seriously :)